# Does an .img image of a single (logical) partition have partition type "Intel/PC partition" or "Non partitioned media"?

Tags: partition-recovery, testdisk

I have an ext4-formatted logical partition `/dev/sda8` and an image file `sda8.img` of it created with `ddrescue` (following the procedure at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009 for similar reasons).  Now I want to recover the file structure of this partition, using `TestDisk`. 
When I run `testdisk sda8.img`, I get this:

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk sda8.img - 195 GB / 182 GiB

Please select the partition table type, press Enter when done.
 [Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
 [EFI GPT] EFI GPT partition map (Mac i386, some x86_64...)
 [Humax  ] Humax partition table
 [Mac    ] Apple partition map
>[None   ] Non partitioned media
 [Sun    ] Sun Solaris partition
 [XBox   ] XBox partition
 [Return ] Return to disk selection



Hint: None partition table type has been detected.
Note: Do NOT select 'None' for media with only a single partition. It's very
rare for a drive to be 'Non-partitioned'.
```

Is it Intel/PC partition or Non partitioned media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all cases, only drives have partition tables, not partitions themselves. Since you had an ext4 filesystem directly on that partition, it definitely doesn't have its own partition table. Therefore, you should pick `None`.